# comparing the key's value of two different map

Tags: java

comparing the key's value of two different map

I have the following two different map's as shown below..

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> multimap1 = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
List<String> someList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
someList1.add("abc");
someList1.add("def");
someList1.add("ght");
multimap1.put(1, someList1);
```

and the other is..

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> multimap2 = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
someList2.add("abc");
someList2.add("wed");
someList2.add("ght");
multimap2.put(1, someList2);
```

Now please advise the logic as I want to compare the values of both the maps with correspond to key that first i take the key
 from first map that is from multimap1 and will also take the first key from multimap2 and then will compare their values that is

```
multimap1       multimap2

1   abc         1  abc
```

folks pls advise the solution as i am stuck in comparison , any help would be appreciated ,Thanks in advance

Comment: What should the comparison do? Test if both lists are equal? What did you try?

Comment: @JBNizet can you please show how to do that as I am not fully grasp the logic, Thanks in advance

Comment: How to do what? I'm asking you what you want to do, and you reply by asking how to do it.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry i misunderstood that actually i want to compare the keys value of both the map one by one that is index wise and where mismatch occurs I wile print on console that mismatch occurs at this index in both the maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not totally clear what you are asking here. If I've understood you correctly, then you want to check if the list in multimap1 is the same (equals) the list in multimap2.

If that's the case, then you need to understand that the value isn't actually "abc" at multimap's 1-key, but rather an object of List;

**multimap1**:

```
Key   Value
 1    List<String>{"abc", "def", "ght"}
```

If you want to test whether the two lists are contain the same elements - and in the same order - simply use

```
multimap1.get(1).equals(multimap2.get(1));
```

Comment: @T Roland ..perfect and Thanks a lot for nice explnation

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly you want to search one map list object value in another list object values.

Either map or list doesn't care about the ordering, you should not use list iterator to get the objects and comparison. If you are sure about map index are unique between two maps then
do the following:

1. Get object which has index 1 from both the maps. Then get the first_list_object(by iterator) value and then do perform:

   ```
   second_list.contains(first_list_object)
   ```
2. Then continue the same logic for next value for `first_list`